# Can we make three different authentication for three different types of user in django and all three will login differently

Tags: django, python-3.x

In my Django web app, I want to create three different types of users. One user can create their account just by entering their credentials and when logging in he will use his username, The next user will be admin, and the third user cannot create his account directly. The third user after entering his credentials, his request to create his account will be sent to the admin and only after the admin verifies him the account will be created else not. And when logging in the third user should use his phone number. As you can see here all three users have different signup and login process and are authenticated differently. Is there any solution to this problem? I searched everywhere but failed to find a solution to this.

Comment: no need to create 3 different authentications, just use one user and set the different roles, you will make it very complicated if you do so.

Comment: @PankajSharma In this particular app, we need them to log in and signup differently so i wanted to create three different authentications.Could you help?

Comment: Please look at this article, am sure you will find what you are looking for here. I use it all the time https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html

Comment: @Mercurial Thanks for your effort but I had already looked this up and this doesn't address my problem